# Driver has null value when using Page object patter design

Tags: c#, sql, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Driver has a null value when i get the value from a BasePage attribute:

```
    public abstract class BasePage
    {
        public static IWebDriver Driver { get; }
        public BasePage(IWebDriver driver)
        {

        }
    }
```

Driver  instance is created in a different class

```
    [Binding]
    public class WebDriverSupport
    {
        private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;
        private ChromeDriver webdriver;

        public WebDriverSupport(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
        {
            this.objectContainer = objectContainer;
        }

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void InitializeWebDriver()
        {
            this.webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
            objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(webdriver);
        }
    }
```

I think that i'm getting the value before instance start. what do you say? 
As all callses use Base class this my be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by:

1 add set to property

```
 public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
```

2 -  pass the driver id  to BasePage.Driver

```
     public void Initialize()
        {
            this.webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
            BasePage.Driver = webdriver;
            objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(this.webdriver);
        }
```